# what does the access 2007 runtime enable me to do?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

i have an access front end. the backend is a sql server database. can i have users download the runtime and have the full functionality of being able to edit the sql server database from the access front end? why is it free? what makes it different from the whole version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a  nutshell, the Access Runtime version allows you to distribute an Access Database application to machines that do not have Access or Office installed. It won't allow you to open the database in design view or to make any changes to the database apart from adding or editing data. They can contain the data tables or can be set up using linked tables so that you have a central database (in some cases a shared .mdb file on a network, or something like SQL server)

Because many Office 2007 installations are not the professional version (Home and Student, Small Business etc) which does not include Access, making the runtime freely available is to encourage Access Developers to build databases which may be used in such cases  or even in instances where office is not installed at all.

Comment: The runtime is binary identical to full Access. It's the installation configuration that prevents you from using the design tools.

Comment: That's really interesting David. Did not know that

Answer (score 1):

See: [Running in Runtime vs. Full Access 2007](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc136539(office.12).aspx#Access2007BuildingRuntimeBasedSolutions_RunninginRuntimevsFullAccess2007)

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, the runtime version allows you to change data but not objects (forms, reports, queries, etc).